# setObject sets the same object for all keys

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in Objective C programming so please bear with me. I have NSMutableDictionary in AppDelegate class which I'm sharing in few view controllers. In one of view controllers I have a method where I'm adding data into NSMutableDictionary and it seems to work fine till I add another object... When I add another object it sets the same object for all keys. My code goes like this:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *myArray;
@synthesize myArray;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    myArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableDictionary *myArrayFromAppDelegate = appDelegate.myArray;

// i'm using keys as strings so i need to convert int to string
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentCuestion];
[myArrayFromAppDelegate setObject:_tempAnswers forKey:key];
[_tempAnswers removeAllObjects];
```

I have checked all values with NSLog, everything seems to be fine, but for some reason it adds the same object for all keys, but not for them one I'm specifying. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you dont name a Dictionary as myArray!

Comment: i know, will change that later, now i need to get this working

Comment: i think you should create the new _tempAnswer instead of removeAllObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[myArrayFromAppDelegate setObject:_tempAnswers forKey:key];
```

stores a *reference* to the dictionary in `myArrayFromAppDelegate`. Therefore, if you
modify `_tempAnswers` later, all the references in the dictionary are affected.

Either create a separate `_tempAnswers` for each key, or store a copy:

```
[myArrayFromAppDelegate setObject:[_tempAnswers copy] forKey:key];
```

Comment: its seem like there is a syntax error in this line: [myArrayFromAppDelegate setObject:[_tempAnswers copy] forKey:key];

Comment: @Domas: It compiles in my project. What error message exactly do you get?

Comment: sorry i have missed something. that worked great! thank you so much!